# Update certificates and OpenSSL on Ubuntu 14.04 and still getting expired LetsEncrypt certificate errors?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

In my office one of the systems is still running Ubuntu 14.04.  This system has been affected by the Let's Encrypt expired root certificate problem:

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

I downloaded manually the latest certificates using the instructions found here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366704/how-to-install-latest-ca-certificates-on-ubuntu-14

```
# Ensure dependencies
sudo apt install make tar wget

# Make a place to build it in
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/ca-certificates/20210119~20.04.2/ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2.tar.xz    
tar -xJf ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2.tar.xz

# Now build and install
cd ca-certificates-20210119~20.04.1
make
sudo make install

# You might want to run this interactively to ensure
# you can select the ISRG Root X1
# in which case, just run: sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh --verbose
/usr/bin/c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs
```

I followed the steps here to remove the "DST Root CA X3" and made sure the "ISRG_Root_X1" certificate was enabled:

https://jay.gooby.org/2021/09/30/remove-the-dst-root-ca-x3-crt-from-ubuntu-14-04-lts

```
# Also available at https://askubuntu.com/a/1366719/233579
mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/ca-    certificates/20210119~20.04.2/ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2.tar.xz
unxz ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2.tar.xz
tar -xf ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2.tar
cd ca-certificates-20210119~20.04.1
make
sudo make install
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -fnoninteractive ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I rebooted to make sure.  I still got the error.  Then I updated manually `openssl` from 1.0.2 to 1.1.0 using these instructions:

https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?resources/installing-openssl-1-1-0-on-ubuntu.21/

```
# I had to use the --no-check-certificate flag because openssl's certificate
#  is issued by LetsEncrypt
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0e.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
tar xzvf openssl-1.1.0e.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.0e
./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'
make
sudo make install
```

I do see the new version:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

I made sure the old expired cert was gone and the new one was active:

```
# Look for expired LetsEncrypt certificate.
$ openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
Can't open /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem for reading, No such file or directory
140352100943680:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem','r')
140352100943680:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load certificate

# Look for new LetsEncrypt ISRG_Root_X1 certificate
$ openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in /etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem
notAfter=Jun  4 11:04:38 2035 GMT
```

I rebooted again just to be sure.  Unfortunately I am still getting the error.  Here is what happens if I try to download the the `openssl` 1.1.0 build again.  However this time, without `--no-check-certificates` with `wget` like I used earlier to get the file:

```
$  wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0e.tar.gz
--2021-11-24 18:38:38--  https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0e.tar.gz
Resolving www.openssl.org (www.openssl.org)... 2600:1403:5400:59f::c1e, 2600:1403:5400:5b3::c1e, 104.122.65.172
Connecting to www.openssl.org (www.openssl.org)|2600:1403:5400:59f::c1e|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.openssl.org's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.openssl.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: 14.04 is EOL. The best way to fix this is to upgrade to a supported version.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to download all the ca certificates if you just wish to add one.

Simply download the new ISRG Root X1 root certificate in PEM format from [Let's Encrypt's repository](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) (having confirmed that the link is to the genuine HTTPS protected site of course).

Rename the file so that it's extension is `.crt` and place in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.

Finally, run:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I don't see how that solves the problem I'm having since even though I did  add more certs than I needed, I do have the cert that should solve the issue, but isn't?